# Problems debugging with eclipse and xdebug

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints, eclipse-pdt

After a long process of trial and error, I finally got xdebug configured correctly but I'm having a few issues with eclipse.

- First, there is only one option in the 'Run > Debug As' menu and it is 'XSL Transformation' and it is grayed out! Why can I select PHP Script or Web Page?
- Second, It just completely ignores my breakpoints!  I set em and eclipse forgets em! It only breaks at the first line and that's it!
- I'm only able to set breakpoints in the first bit of php - so if I have a few lines of PHP, followed by HTML and then followed by some more PHP, there is no blue area in the far left bar to set breakpoints.

Am I just completely missing something here?  I'm running WAMP and Eclipse for PHP Developers (Helios).  Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you running vanilla Eclipse, Eclipse and PDT, or Eclipse with Zend Studio? Your title, question body and tagging disagree with each other here...

Comment: I put the zend-studio in there just because they are basically the same apps.  I'm running eclipse for php.

Comment: "Eclipse for PHP" isn't a thing.  Are you talking about [Eclipse with PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/)?

Comment: It must be just plain eclipse then - in the about it says"Eclipse for PHP Developers

Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911"

Comment: I was under the impression that PDT contained a server (like Zend or whatever).

Comment: [Aha, found it](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliosr)!  Yeah, you're running PDT.

Comment: ok, makes sense - I just had a little bit of language confusion there, sorry about that.

Comment: No worries.  Unfortunately I haven't had the opportunity to use the debugger Eclipse/PDT provides.  I use Komodo.

Comment: komodo IDE?  I've been thinking about making the move to it because I use Edit and like it a lot.  I just installed netbeans and I'm going to give it a go, people say the debugging is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Tried out NetBeans and it is working great - I've already isolated what my issue was.  Eclipse seems like it is the better/more-complete IDE, however I don't have time to mess around with it anymore - NetBeans FTW, maybe I'll checkout eclipse again when i'm not so noobish.